# batch variable nested into a batch variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, nested

Depending on the text after 'X' and before 'Open file' in mypath variable, I want to call a function passing this text as argument in order to replace it by 'foo'. To do it, I have written

```
@echo off
SET mypath=Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board Airport\X\Dashboard\Open file
if /i %1=="Dashboard" goto label %1
if /i %1=="Dboard" goto label %1

:label 
SET mypath=%mypath:\%1\=foo%
ECHO %mypath%
```

I notice that echoing mypath at the end of that script outputs

```
Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board Airport\X\Dashboard\Open file  instead of 
Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board Airport\X\foo\Open file
```

I think of the issue is about parameter %1 within 'SET mypath=%mypath:\%1\=foo%', but I don't understand why.

In fact I absolutely need to use parameter %1 because the text which is currently "Dashboard" into mypath variable is not a static text. It can be "Dboard", or anything

Someone could explain me? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For string manipulations with variables you need `delayed expansion`:

```
@echo off
SET mypath=Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board Airport\X\Dashboard\Open file
if /i %1=="Dashboard" goto label %1
if /i %1=="Dboard" goto label %1

:label 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET mypath=!mypath:\%~1\=foo!
ECHO %mypath%
```

..output is:

```
Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board Airport\XfooOpen file
```

Comment: DOING myfile.bat "Dboard" my output is Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board Airport\X\Dashboard\Open file, not the me as you;

Comment: and its normal to be.YOu want to replace DASHBOARD with FOO but if you pass DBOARD nothing will be replaced.

Comment: Yes, if you want replace "Dboard", you must search for "Dboard" and if search failed, nothing can replaced.

Comment: I'm foolish! It's very good, it's due to a lack of vigilance. Thank you very much

Comment: +1, But your compares are useless, as they will never match `"Dasboard"` nor `"Dboard"`, as the texts are quoted but `%1` not. Currently it works, as `:label` is always reached. Even if you fix it, the `%1` in `goto label %1` is pointless as goto doesn't use parameters

Comment: Btw. None of the answers works with a path like `C:\Documents & Settings\Dboard\file`. Therefore it's always a good idea to enclose SET commands `SET "mypath=!mypath:\%~1\=foo!"`

Answer (score 3):

Excuse me. Sometimes I think I don't really understand the questions (perhaps because my mother tongue is not English).

In your question you said you want to replace "the text after 'X' and before 'Open file' in mypath variable... by 'foo'" and even you said "text which is currently "Dashboard" into mypath variable is not a static text. It can be "Dboard", or anything", but in your code and posterior comments in the answers it seems that you just want to change the strings "Dashboard" or "Dboard" by "foo". This confuses me.

Anyway, this is my solution to *your question* (not to your comments).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET mypath=Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board Airport\X\Dashboard\Open file

rem Get the text after 'X' and before 'Open file'
set auxPath=%mypath%
set enclosed=
set text=
:nextPart
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=\" %%a in ("%auxPath%") do (
      if "%%a" equ "Open file" (set enclosed=) else (
      if defined enclosed (set "text=!text!\%%a") else (
      if "%%a" equ "X" (set enclosed=1)
      ))
      set "auxPath=%%b"
   )
if defined auxPath goto nextPart
set text=%text:~1%

rem Replace that text by "foo"
call :Change "%text%"
goto :EOF

:Change
SET mypath=!mypath:\%~1\=\foo\!
ECHO %mypath%
exit /B
```

For example, the output of previous program is this:

```
Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board Airport\X\foo\Open file
```

But if mypath variable would be this:

```
Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board Airport\X\One\Two three\Open file
```

... the output would be this:

```
Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board Airport\X\foo\Open file
```

... that precisely solves your request.

Comment: +1, best answer except one point: the OP wrote text after "X"   not after  "X\"   :)

Comment: @Endoro: Yes. In the context of the question, it seems that both `X` and `Open file` strings should be delimited by left-slash characteres (and also the replaced `foo` string). This point is confirmed by OP's expected output: `Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board Airport\X\foo\Open file` that, by the while, is not addressed by anyone of the other answers...

Answer (score 2):

```
        @echo off
        SET mypath=Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board Airport\X\Dashboard\Open file

        if /i "%~1"=="Dashboard" goto :label 
        if /i "%~1"=="Dboard" goto :label 

        goto :eof
        :label
        rem set temp_var=%~1
        rem call SET mypath=%%mypath:%temp_var%=foo%%
        rem echo %mypath%
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
        set mypath=!mypath:%~1=foo!
        ECHO !mypath!
    endlocal
```

Could you try this?

Comment: Intresting issue: we have 40' time and post to the same minute `:-)`

Comment: I try it and it doesn't change issue!

Comment: Ok.I've made more changes in your code.This will work only if the parameter is  Dashboard as there is no Dboard in initial value of mypath. You can try also the commented part

Comment: Issue persists. value of mypath doesn't change!

Comment: then just `set mypath=!mypath:Dashboard=foo!` ... It will be changed but you'll miss the case with `Dboard`

Comment: It's just small part of my script. In fact I absolutely need to use parameter %1 because the text which is currently "Dashboard" is not static. It can be "Dboard", or anything

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was the search/replace using a `%1` :-
 `SET mypath=%mypath:\%1\=foo%` has too many `%` characters upsetting the syntax a bit.

This answer was to use `EnableDelayedExpansion` to take advantage of the `!` syntax, but beware the %mypath% variable will lose its value after `endlocal` - it only keeps its value within the `setlocal` block.

One way around this is to write the `SET` command to a temporary batch file, and call it after the local block :

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  SET mypath=!mypath:%1=foo!
     rem  Create a batch file to perform SET later : 
  echo @SET mypath=%mypath% > "%TEMP%\setmyvar.bat"
endlocal

   rem  Now use the batch file to set the variable :
call "%TEMP%\setmyvar.bat"
ECHO %mypath%
```

If there's a more elegant way to do this, please let us know :)

Comment: `has too many % characters upsetting the syntax a bit.`  ?  OMG! You **must**  see some of my really `%`  upsetting codes!